# Рассылка нескольким клиентам через SocketServer Delphi

Tags: delphi, сервер, сокет, клиент-сервер, клиент

Есть приложение-сервер, есть приложение-клиент, на первом реализована отправка файла клиенту. Все работает, но хотелось бы чтобы рассылка шла не одному клиенту, а всем подключенным.

Пробовал через цикл, но т.к. файл разбивается при втором проходе цикла появляется ошибка доступа к файлу. Хотел через sleep сделать, но подумал долго и понял, что не выйдет. В какую сторону смотреть? Не хочу уходит от сокетов, с ними по крайней мере основная функция работает.

прилагаю ссылку на ГИТ
https://github.com/WOLF33/EasyLan-v5.git

Comment: В боевой эксплуатации даже этот код будет периодически приводить к порче данных. Вы не обратили внимания на фразу в моем ответе на предыдущий вопрос: `методы отправки данных в сокет и получения их из сокета - это функции и они возвращают количество реально прочитанных/записанных данных.`

Comment: У меня это курсовая работа, сдать один раз и забыть, главное чтобы сработала 1 раз. Получается не реализовать такую возможность?

Comment: "но т.к. файл разбивается при втором проходе" - ну так не разбивайте его! )

Comment: а если не разбивать, то он просто не доходит в целости и сохранности

Answer (score 1):

Вам нужно для каждого клиента запускать свой поток для передачи файла. Чтобы каждый поток мог читать файл не зависимо от других и не мешая другим, нужно в каждом потоке создавать свой `TFileStream` не блокируя при этом чтение этого файла  для других потоков. Например вот так:

```
FS := TFileStream.Create(
  CreateFile(PChar('filename'), GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, nil, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0)
);
```

И дальше каждый поток читает файл независимо от других и передает его на своего клиента.

Comment: если под потоками вы подразумеваете `TThread`, то у автора неблокирующий режим работы сокета. Там используется механизм событий, а не потоки. А в целом - да, на каждое соединение - нужен отдельный `TStream`.

Comment: @kami да, я имел ввиду исполняющиеся потоки. В вопросе про события нет ни слова. В таком случае нужно в основном потоке создавать пачку файлстримов и обрабатывать события соответствующим образом.

Comment: @kot-da-vinci  
Можно более раскрыто про потоки рассказать? куда именно дописать код и какой?

Comment: @МаксимКутенков Какой код и куда писать - решать вам. Что конкретно про потоки вы хотите узнать?

Comment: @kot-da-vinci Код который вы привели, как я понял, нужно записать  в обработчик создания потока, но как мне потом обращаться к каждому потоку чтобы разослать все файлы каждому клиенту?

Comment: Код, который я привел, создает объект класса `TFileStream` из файла с именем `filename` в текущей директории. С указанными параметрами можно создавать сколько угодно таких независимых объектов из одного и того же файла. Что делать дальше с этими объектами вам нужно придумать самому.